# Расширение файла в ссылке(регулярные выражения)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите проверить ссылку на наличие расширения файла на конце,т.е что есть точка и типы файлов за ней (.html; .htm; .png; .jpeg и т.д.).

Например, ссылка вида `component/tv/samsung/21.html` - должна соответствовать определенному регулярному выражению.

Я попробовал составить и вот, что у меня получилось:

```
if (preg_match('/^component\/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]*)\/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]*)\/(.+)$/i',
   'component/tv/samsung/21.html', $matches)) { 
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Но хотелось бы заменить (.+) на более строгое условие. Помогите, кто знает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
/^component\/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]*)\/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]*)\/(.+)(html|htm|png|jpeg)$/i
```

или

```
/^component\/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]*)\/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]*)\/(.+)\.(html|htm|png|jpeg)$/i
```

Comment: `component/tv/samsung/21/?type=.jpeg` ?..

Answer (score 0):

[Как вариант](https://regex101.com/r/gX6qC0/4): `^component\/([\w-%~]+)\/([\w-%~]+)\/([\w-%~]*\.\w*)$`, если вы точно знаете что у вас две папки в пути и после них имя файла. Если точно количество папок не известно, то запрос сильно усложнится.
[\w-%~] захватывает a_z,A_Z,0_9,_ и дополнительно '-', '%', '~' (пробел в ссылке - %20, например). Возможно навскидку ещё какие-либо допустимые символы пропустил.

---

Вместо последнего `\w*` можно, конечно, жёстко задать расширения файлов, но только если вы уверены что знаете их все и что они не будут изменяться: `(htm|html|php|jpg|jpeg|...)`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Подскажите, пожалуйста, если количество папок не известно. Например, для всех ссылок на сайте.

Comment: Правильно ли будет: `/^(.+\.\w*)$/i`?

Comment: Вам надо просто проверить ссылку на наличие точки и расширения или извлечь из неё какие-то части?.. 
Если просто проверить то, наверное, лучше будет вот так: `/^([^\?#]+\.\w*)(?:[\?#].*)?$/i`, т.к. ссылка может содержать параметры (?param=value) и закладки (#bookmark).
В результате такой RegEx захватит только ссылку (без параметров), если она содержит в себе имя файла. И данный regex не не проверяет ссылку на валидность, т.к. считает что она изначально корректная.
Проверить можно здесь: https://regex101.com/r/rC9yU7/1

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!